# how to clear entries from several EditTexts?

Tags: android

I am new to java and android so please forgive me if i am asking to simple question. 
I have an application which requires user input in two EditTexts. Those inputs are multipied and result is displayed in TextView. I would like to use "clear entries" button which would clear the content of user entries and displayed result. Is there any way to do it?

Here is an application code.

```
package c.example.rectangle;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText l;
     EditText w;
     TextView a;
     Button b;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        l = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.length);
        w = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.width);
        a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblarea);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        b.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        calculateRectangle(l.getText().toString(), w.getText().toString());


    }
    private void calculateRectangle(String clength, String cwidth){


        double area = Double.parseDouble(clength)*Double.parseDouble(cwidth);

        a.setText(String.valueOf(area)); 
}}
```

And here is my XML Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#8B4513"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#2F4F4F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/rect"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8B4513"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#2F4F4F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cm"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/length"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#2F4F4F"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/help"
            android:inputType="text" />


    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8B4513"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#2F4F4F"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/breadth"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/width"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"   
        android:background="#2F4F4F"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/help"

        android:ems="10" 
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/calculate"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
     android:layout_marginRight="100dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/calculate"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8B4513"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/label4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:background="#2F4F4F"
     android:text="@string/area"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/lblarea"
     android:layout_width="110dp"
     android:layout_height="21dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:background="#2F4F4F"
     android:gravity="center"/>
 </LinearLayout>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/clear"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
     android:layout_marginRight="100dip"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:text="@string/clear" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would be very appreciate for the answer.

Comment: You've got a lot of great answers here! Consider marking one of them viewed to close out this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set both editTexts to empty when you no longer need the data in them to be displayed?

```
EditText.setText("");
```

Same thing with the TextView;

```
TextView.setText("");
```

Comment: I agree. That's what I was about to write.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a clear button, do the following.

Create a Button in your xml:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/clear_button"
     ... you own layout prefs ...
/>
```

Create a listener for the button in your code:

```
OnClickListener clearButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {          
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_for_text_box_a)).setText("");
    //...do this for all your edit texts that you want to clear         
  }
};
```

Connect the listener to the button

```
Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_button);
clearButton.setOnClickListener(clearButtonListener);
```

Alternatively, instead of finding the edit texts by id in the listener, they could be instance variables that get initialized in `onCreate` or wherever. I would also recommend not using one letter variable names.

Personally, I would set `OnClickListener`s instead of the `onClick` attribute in the XML. Although using the XML `onClick` attribute may amount to fewer lines of code, it unfortunately creates a very tight coupling of layout and functionality. I prefer to have XML for layout, and Java for functionality. Additionally, being forced to use `id`s amounts to requiring XML elements to have variable names, which makes for more readable layout code (what is this button? what is this checkbox for?). Another problem I see with using the `onClick` attribute is that it forces your methods called to be public, which doesn't really make sense for many of these methods. *I prefer to understand what an Activity does functionally through reading the Java, and I would rather not have unreferenced public methods floating around in my Activities.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to iterate through them, you can put them in a list then use a for loop to set the text to ""

```
List<EditText> myList = new List<EditText>();
myList.add(editText1);
```

Then in your clear method

```
for (int x = 0; x < myList.size(); x++

{   
myList.get(x).setText("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. I did not try codeMagic answear but it also looks fine. Thank You again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it solved. They all would do the job. When I first read your question I thought you wanted to do them all at once by iterating over them. If you accept the answer that you did use, it will help others with the same problem find it easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Why nobody seems to use the really useful [android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) ?

```
<Button
    ...
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    android:onClick="calculate" />
<Button
    ...
    android:text="@string/clear"
    android:onClick="clearForm" />
```

With the following activity :

```
class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    ...
    /**
     * Calculate
     * android:onClick="calculate"
     */
    public void calculate(View view)
    {
        // Handle click on your 'Calculate' button
    }

    /**
     * Clear form
     * android:onClick="clearForm"
     */
    public void clearForm(View view)
    {
        int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.length, R.id.width};
        for(int id : ids)
        {
            ((EditText) this.findViewById(id).)setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you do not have to care about ids and your code will be more clean than clean.

Ids should not be overused! They are great on views that can be 'changed' by the user to handle those changes (and to enjoy the onSaveInstanceState() natural behavior) but that's it!

IMO.

Comment: I prefer a looser coupling between layout and functionality. See my updated answer for my two cents :)

Comment: Coupling? In a way.
I never use more than one layout for one activity, but sometimes I use one layout for more than one activity... and then implement these android:onClick methods.
So indeed, I agree, there is a coupling, but is it a bad one for an Android application design and for a clear and clean source code? ;)